# How to Create a Wide Table in Python GridDB Client for Smart Meter Data and Sensor Readings?

Tags: python, database, griddb

I'm working on a project that involves handling data from smart meters and sensor readings using the Python GridDB client. Here are the specific requirements:

1. **Data from Active Smart Meters**: I have a set of active smart meters configured to send data at specific times of the day. Each meter publishes data at the designated time.
2. **Combining Meter Data**: I need to create a table or function that can automatically combine the data from all active smart meters when they have published data at a particular time. This combined data should be stored for further analysis.
3. **Sensor Readings**: Additionally, I have sensor readings associated with each smart meter. These readings include data such as readings, battery status, temperature, and network signal strength.
4. **Narrow to Wide Table**: The goal is to transform the narrow table format (individual readings for each meter) into a separate wide table format suitable for reporting and analysis functions.

I've started exploring the Python GridDB client, but I'm unsure about the specific functions and methods I should use to achieve these data-handling tasks. Here's a simplified representation of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import griddb_python as griddb
import csv
import datetime

def combine_meter_data(gridstore, meters_container, readings_container):
    meters_query = gridstore.query(meters_container, "select *")
    readings_query = gridstore.query(readings_container, "select *")

    combined_data = []

    for meter in meters_query:
        meter_id = meter[0]
        meter_name = meter[1]

        combined_meter_data = {
            'meter_id': meter_id,
            'meter_name': meter_name,
            'readings': []
        }

        readings_query.set_column(0, meter_id)
        readings = readings_query.fetch(False)

        for reading in readings:
            reading_data = {
                'timestamp': reading[1],
                'reading_value': reading[2],
                'battery_status': reading[3],
                'temperature': reading[4],
                'network_signal_strength': reading[5]
            }

            combined_meter_data['readings'].append(reading_data)

        combined_data.append(combined_meter_data)

    return combined_data

def main():
    factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
    argv = ["host", "port", "cluster_name", "username", "password"]

    try:
        gridstore = factory.get_store(
           host=argv[0],
           port=argv[1],
           cluster_name=argv[2],
           username=argv[3],
           password=argv[4]
        )

        with open("payments.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("Payments",
                                           [["timestamp", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
                                            ["amount", griddb.Type.FLOAT],
                                            ["transaction_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
                                            ["payment_phone_number", griddb.Type.STRING]],
                                           griddb.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES)
            ts = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)

            for row in reader:
                timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(row["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                amount = float(row["amount"])
                transaction_id = row["transaction_id"]
                payment_phone_number = row["payment_phone_number"]
                ts.put([timestamp, amount, transaction_id, payment_phone_number])

        print("Payments data stored in Database.")

        
        data_unprocessed = [
            # test mock data from sensors
            {'timestamp': '2023-09-14 12:00:00', 'value': 25.5},
            {'timestamp': '2023-09-14 12:15:00', 'value': 27.8},
            
        ]

        #  sensor data container details 
        data_container_info = griddb.ContainerInfo("SensorData", [["timestamp", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP], ["value", griddb.Type.FLOAT]], griddb.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES)
        data_container = gridstore.put_container(data_container_info)

        # Insert rows into my container container
        for row in data_unprocessed:
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            value = float(row['value'])
            data_container.put([timestamp, value])

        print("Finished and stored in Database.")

        
        combined_data = combine_meter_data(gridstore, 'meters_container', 'readings_container')

        
        wide_table_container = gridstore.put_container(wide_table_container)
        for data in combined_data:
            wide_table_container.put(data)

        print("Meter data all stored in the wide table.")

    except griddb.GSException as e:
        print(e)
        for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
            print(e.get_message(i))
```

I'm expecting guidance on how to create the combine_meter_data function using Python GridDB client functions and internal GridDB functions to handle the data merging and transformation tasks effectively.